# Deserializing Json string with C# using Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have read some articles but didnt fix my problem , i have a problem with JSON string when deserialize, here the string

```
{"table":"sy_version","effected":2,"data":[{"mod_id":"CS","sub_mod":"sbm_sl.exe","version":"2015.11.07.1","upload_date ":"2015-11-10 11:34:13"},{"mod_id":"FA","sub_mod":"sbm_fa.exe","version":"2015.11.09","upload_date ":"2015-11-10 11:34:13"}]}
```

And this is my class

```
    public class Datum
    {
        public string mod_id { get; set; }
        public string sub_mod { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public DateTime upload_date { get; set; }
    }

    public class sy_periode
    {
        public string table { get; set; }
        public int effected { get; set; }
        public IList<Datum> datas { get; set; }
    }

    public static void test(string str) {
        // dynamic sy_periode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
        var sy_periode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sy_periode>(str);
        foreach (var data in sy_periode.datas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.sub_mod);
        }

    }
```

When I executed, string **table** and **effected** have value, but **datas** is null, this is the error message

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Use the IDEs built in debugger; it's a lot quicker than using StackOverflow as a debugger. Even a quick look over the code would pick up the typo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be `datas`, it should have the same name as JSON object: `data`.

Here is the correct classes structure:

```
public class Datum
{
    public string mod_id { get; set; }
    public string sub_mod { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public DateTime upload_date { get; set; }
}

public class sy_periode
{
    public string table { get; set; }
    public int effected { get; set; }
    public IList<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Also, note that in JSON your `upload_date` properties have an odd whitespace in the end: `upload_date`. It may be a typo. However, if it is an actual input and since C# member name cannot contain spaces, you can try to specify the name in order to serialize it:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "upload_date ")]
public DateTime upload_date { get; set; }
```

I am not quite sure that it will work, but I see no reasons of why it shouldn't.

Comment: That it is, Thanks for your help.